# Display items in the Nativescript ListView

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, angular, nativescript

I am learning Nativescript with Angular 2 and trying to get Random user data from `https://randomuser.me` API. I am not able to display just the names of 10 random users in the ListView. It only displays 10 blank List Items in the ListView.

Here is my app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class AppComponent {
    public names: Observable<Array<Object>>;

constructor(public http: Http){

}

public onTap(){
    this.getData()
    .subscribe(
        (res) => {
            this.names = res.json().results;
        }
    );
}

public getData(){
    return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10');

}
```

}

And here is my html template file

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button text="GET" (tap)="onTap()"></Button>
    <ListView [items]="names">
        <template let-item="item">
            <Label (text)="item.gender" textWrap="true"></Label>        
        </template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `<Label (text)="item.gender" textWrap="true"></Label>` to 
`<Label [text]="item.gender" textWrap="true"></Label>`

Comment: Any help on how to use `StackLayout` inside the `template`. It gives me error that I cannot have multiple components inside the template.

Comment: can you put here an example of how you use it?

Comment: This is how I am trying to use it.
`<StackLayout>
    <TextField hint="Email"></TextField>
    <Button text="GET" (tap)="onTap()"></Button>
    <ListView [items]="names">
        <template let-item="item">
            <StackLayout>
                <Image [src]="item.picture.large" stretch="none"></Image>
                <Label [text]="item.name.first"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
                    
        </template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>`

Comment: I tested the code you mentioned above but I couldn't reproduce the issue, it worked.

Comment: here is the picture of it http://imgur.com/4sXzeyV I just paste all your codes you just put them to in this post.

Comment: Yes, it worked, I recompiled the whole project again after closing the console and it just worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have made a mistake in the way you have added the binding for the `text` property in the ListView item `Template`. Simply change the `(text)="item.gender"` to `[text]="item.gender"`.

Note that for "*One-way from data source to view target*" in angular 2 you should use the `[]` syntax, the `()` is an "*One-way from view target to data source*" and for example could be used for event handlers.

[Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax) you can find more details about angular binding syntax.